# Loopback: Store object from remote method for later reuse within the Server

Tags: javascript, database, rest, loopbackjs

**So I am getting into remote methods and I am thinking on a logic challenge:**

Instead of re-querying the Database every time, when a remote method is called, I would like to store the response object I am giving back to the remote method caller.

As long as the data in the Database does not change, the response for the remote call would always be the same, hence the database call would not be necessary.

- Does there exist way to store such a variable (that can contain a considerable amount of data), so that
  it would be available for a different remote method and/or a later
  call of the same method?
- Do I think in a strange direction?
- Would it be better to manage such issues on the client and reduce the REST API calls (Which I also try to keep at a minimum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does there exist way to store such a variable (that can contain a considerable amount of data), so that it would be available for a different remote method and/or a later call of the same method?

`server/boot/storage.js`

```
module.exports = (server) => {
    server.variable = 'thing I want to store';
}
```

`server/boot/storage-methods.js`

```
module.exports = (server) => {
    server.models.Model1.accessGlobalStorage= async () => {return server.variable};
    server.models.Model2.accessGlobalStorage= async () => {return server.variable};
    // Insert remote method definition here
}
```

> Do I think in a strange direction?

No, this is the idea behind lots of things like [redis](https://redis.io/), which is a much more conventional, and scalable way to do what you're doing.

> Would it be better to manage such issues on the client and reduce the REST API calls (Which I also try to keep at a minimum)?

http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

*Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs*

Comment: Hey Thanks Marvin. Works great. You got me there with the Premature Optimization article XD. I'll keep redis in mind for my next project.

Comment: I am able to call the server.variable in my model via this.accessGlobalStorage. The thing I have changed is the variable name "server". Loopbacks documentation names it "app".